# Adding animation to element appearing to be swooping from one of the window/document border with fade-in effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add FadeIn Effect upon Viewport Just Like in this codePen :
https://codepen.io/treppin/pen/BWeKRY

So I created a fadeIn-Right css with sort of animation and tried adding the class to Element when it comes in viewport (only once) But it's not working. Where did I get wrong.

I want it to be just like the above [example](https://codepen.io/treppin/pen/BWeKRY) with some changes like appearing to be swooping in from right/left

```js
function checkElementLocation() {
                var $window = $(window);
                var bottom_of_window = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();

                $('.elem').each(function (i) {
                    var $that = $(this);
                    var bottom_of_object = $that.position().top + $that.outerHeight();

                    if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                        $(this).addClass('fadeIn-Right');
                    }
                });
            }
            checkElementLocation();
            $(window).on('scroll', function () {
                checkElementLocation();
            });
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: bisque;
        }
        .content {
            width: 30%;
            margin: 100px 0;
            padding: 50px 100px;
            height: auto;
        }
        .r1 {background-color: #3b599877;}
        .r2 {background-color: red;}
        .r3 {background-color: #3b5998;}
        .r4 {background-color: green;}
        .r5 {background-color: #3b5998da;}

        
        .fadeIn-Right {
            animation: fadeRight 3s ease-in-out  forwards;
        }
        @keyframes fadeRight {
            0% {
                transform: translateX(-20px);
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
                transform: none;
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div  class="elem content r1">
            Hello World
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
        </div>
        <div class="elem content r2  ">
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
        </div>
        <div class="elem  content r3 ">
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
        </div>
        <div class="elem content r4 ">
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
        </div>
        <div class="elem content r5" >
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
            "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Expected behavior about fadeIn effect is not clear. transform property applied only moves the element. If you want to create an effect like element coming out from right to left, then your animation could be :
```
@keyframes fadeRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
``` 
But that's me taking guess what you need. requirement is not very clear

Comment: Check your browser's devtools inspect facility console for errors. And have a careful look at the code loaded in the codepen you cite. You'll see they load some libraries, including jquery.

Comment: @RaviChaudhary yes, this is exactly what I want 'element coming out from right to left'

Answer (score 0):

For adding animation where the element appears to be swooping in from right to left, you could simply use transform property(you are already using that) but value has be `translateX(100%)` so that it appears to be swooping in from window border on the right

```
@keyframes fadeRight {
   0% {
      transform: translateX(100%);
      opacity: 0;
   } 
   100% {
      transform: none;
      opacity: 1;
   }
}
```